# Which is bigger, the number of neurons in the brain or the all the stars in the observable universe?

Tags: inequality

In other words, is 100 billion larger than $10^{22}$ or ....?

Are there also other interesting comparisons of systems with large number of members?  i.e. the sand on the beach, the atoms in the air, etc.

Update: If we have $10^{11}$ per human brain, is the sum of all neurons on the planet larger than the number of stars in the observable universe?

Comment: $100$ billion = $10^{11}$.

Comment: For the update, if you consider non-humans as well, I think the answer is still no, but it's a close call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100 billion is the number $1$ followed by eleven zeroes: $100,000,000,000$, so it's $10^{11}$, which means $10^{22}$ is bigger because it has a bigger exponent with the same base.